# SOCKS proxy that can bind to NIC for windows?

Tags: windows, networking, proxy

My computer has two NICs and I want to use some applications with a specific NIC.

I thought the best way to do this in my scenario would be install a SOCKS proxy server on my computer, bind the SOCKS proxy server to my NIC and then have the browser use the SOCKS proxy.

Are there any SOCKS proxy servers for windows that support binding to NICs?

Answer (score 1):

[WinGate](http://www.wingate.com) will allow this.  You can choose which interface(s) to bind to for client connections, and you can also choose which interface to bind to for outgoing connections made on behalf of the client.  There is also a free 10 user version, and all connections from the local computer are free in any case.

You may also be able to do this by routing.  If these apps connect to specific sites, then if you add routes for these destination IPs, you can specify the interface to use.  The OS chooses the local IP to bind to based on the interface which matches the route to the destination.

Disclaimer: I work for Qbik who make WinGate.

Comment: Does WinGate support UDP over SOCKS?

Comment: Yes, it supports UDP associate command.